# How do I access an element in a CuArray of Julia and change its value?

Tags: julia, julia-gpu

I want to change only one element, as shown in the code below.

```
using Flux, CuArrays

a = rand(3,3) |> gpu
CuArrays.allowscalar(false)
a[1, 1] = 1.0f0
```

Because allowscalar is set to false, it is natural that it will appear as below.

```
ERROR: scalar setindex! is disallowed
```

But if allowscalar is removed, it will appear as below.

```
Performing scalar operations on GPU arrays: This is very slow, consider disallowing these operations with allowscalar(false)
```

I turned "allowscalar" on and off before and after the part that accesses the element.
Then, it was about 20 times slower than when "allowscalar" was set to true.

Next, I tried to create another matrix once on the CPU and then add up the matrices on the GPU, as shown below.

```
b = zeros(Float32, 3, 3)
b[1, 1] = 1.0f0
b = b |> gpu
a .+= b
```

However, it is about 4 times faster if I assume that I can do it on the GPU alone such as below.

```
a .*= 1.0f0 # Dummy calculations that do some processing on the GPU
a .+= a # Dummy calculations that do some processing on the GPU
```

How do I access an element in a CuArray and change its value?
I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I turned "allowscalar" on and off before and after the part that accesses the element. Then, it was about 20 times slower than when "allowscalar" was set to true.

Toggling `allowscalar` should not affect performance. In fact, CuArrays itself does so when it needs to inspect individual elements with certain APIs. A macro version of the function makes it easy to do so:

```
julia> a = CuArrays.rand(3,3);

julia> CuArrays.allowscalar(false)

julia> a[1, 1] = 1.0f0
ERROR: scalar setindex! is disallowed

julia> CuArrays.@allowscalar a[1, 1] = 1.0f0
1.0f0

julia> a
3×3 CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}:
 1.0       0.277899   0.333898
 0.126213  0.0881365  0.794662
 0.94518   0.586488   0.656359

julia> a[1, 1] = 1.0f0
```